# IS there a way to determine if a bluetooth device is a headset other than from device class or major class?

Tags: android, class, bluetooth, headset

I'm using device class to determine if a handsfree headset is connected. But I found out that Qnine 3.0 doesn't have a distinguishable device id or class id. Both of which are zeros.  Android OS knows that it is a headset and update the status icon--But for my app, I need an alternative way to determine that it is a headset.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SDP (service discovery protocol) to query the device for the list of supported profiles.  Then you can see that the device supports Headset Profile or Hands Free Profile.

Comment: That works. Thanks. Not sure why Android didn't keep those IDs.